# Conversion from degrees to radians not accurate enough

Tags: c#, trigonometry

I know very well how conversion from degrees to radians works, but I still have a problem with it. The problem is its accuracy.

As you probably know trigonometric functions from `System.Math` library use radians, but I needed trigonometric functions, in which you plug degrees. So I created a `Helper` class with `Cos`,`Sin` and `Tan` functions, which would just convert degrees to radians inside of them and call their `Math` functions.

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static double Sin(double degrees) => Math.Sin(degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
    public static double Cos(double degrees) => Math.Cos(degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
    public static double Tan(double degrees) => Math.Tan(degrees * Math.PI / 180.0);
}
```

But, for example, when I use `Math.Tan(45)` it returns 0.999999999989 instead of one. My question to you, my fellow friends, is how to make this totally accurate.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I understand, there will be small errors and it's impossible to get rid of them. What I exactly want to know is how to round the value by the needed amount (not too much, not too little) so it works anyway.

EDIT2:
Context is very important in this question, so here it is:

I need trigonometry for my `Line` class which has following constructor:

```
public Line(Vector2 beginning, Vector2 end)
{
    this.beginning = beginning;
    this.end = end;
    this.direction = 180.0 * Math.Atan(end.Y - beginning.Y / end.X - beginning.X) / Math.PI;
    this.slope = Helper.Tan(direction);
    this.length = Helper.DistanceBetweenTwoPoints(beginning, end);
    this.offset = beginning.X;
 }
```

The problem arises with the line where I assign the value for the slope, which I need for checking if a point is on this line using linear algebra.

DISCLOSURE: `Vector2` is a structure with `double x` and `double y`. That's all.

Answer (score 3):

You will always have rounding errors when using doubles. That's the very nature of floating point arithmetics. Double can carry approximatly 16 decimal digits. And on every operation the error adds up. The "trick" is to accept this error, never compare doubles/ floats with equality (unless you know what you are doing) and do meaningful rounding on output.

See http://floating-point-gui.de/.

To decide if a point lies on a line between two points or similar problems, you don't need to round but use a tolerance: calculate the shortest distance between the point and the line and check if it is below a threshold. How large this threshold can/ should be depends on your application and there is no easy answer. If for example your points are in the range of 0..10, a tolerance of 1e-7 would be reasonable for me. If you want a generic implementation you should take the maximum of

- the distance of the points times a factor (e.g. `dist(begin, end) * 1e-8`)
- an absolute value for very small distances (e.g. `1e-10`)

But you can still run into problems. For example, if you line goes from `(10000000.1,0)` to `(10000000.2,0)`, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance) for details. This is a broad topic in general.

Comment: I know there will always be errors, and I also know why. Maybe i asked my question the wrong way

Comment: @huB1erTi2: extended the answer a bit. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Well, I needed **total** accuracy, but I know that is impossible, so what I really need is a convenient way to round the value, but not too much.

Comment: For *total* accuraccy take a look at GNU MPL. For rounding: The error is approximatly 1.5m on the distance earth<->sun. How much you can round depends on your application but 6-8 digits are normally than enough.

Comment: I think it's better if I'll give you context, wait a sec

Comment: Seems that the obvious has been skipped, PI is an irrational number, any calculations using PI or any other irrational number will be inaccurate no matter what number system or algorithm you use. BTW @PeterSchneider your  error approximation is around 6 orders of magnitude out. Using doubles `sin(1e-17) * 1.5e11` Earth<->Sun has an error of ~1.5µm (millionths of a meter)

Answer (score 1):

Using the slope that you get via `Helper.Tan(direction)` to calculate if a point is on a line is going to produce a differing amounts of error for different slopes that get get worse as direction approaches `+/- PI / 2` because `tan(x)` approaches infinity as `x` approaches `+/- PI/2` and at `+/- PI/2` it will not work at all.

To see if a point is near a line use the cross product of the line's vector and the vector to the point. Eg the line is from point `A` to `B` and the point is `P` then `Cross(B-A,P-A)` will be zero when `P` is on the line. To combat the error which is related to the line length divide the cross product by the line length squared and compare to a arbitrary small tolerance `epsilon`.

```
// A,B, P are Vector2
double cross = (B.x-A.x) * (P.y-A.y) - (B.y-A.y) * (P.x-A.x);
cross /= (B.x-A.x) * (B.x-A.x) + (B.y-A.y) * (B.y-A.y);
double epsilon = 1.0e-6; // 1 millionths of a unit
if (Math.abs(cross) < epsilon) {
     // point P is on line A,B
}
```

BTW Math.PI is an approximation of an irrational number, using it will always introduce an error no matter what system you use. PI simply can not be written as a number. In the real world all measurements have an error and for all practical applications of PI 7 digits 3.141592 are more than enough precision.

Comment: Excellent answer. To avoid the inherent problems with PI, just store numbers as degrees in memory/persistent memory, and convert as needed. People seem to forget why degrees were invented... to have an easy way to divide right angles by 2, 3, 6, 10, etc. For that purpose, they are excellent. It is easy enough to round to the nearest 100th or 1000th of a degree, if the user inputs degrees. For PI, storing the fraction of one PI is the best you can do.